# Vba - Convert number to decimal when using SQL on Ms Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Trying to convert a number value to decimal, with two decimals (,00), in vba when selecting value from MS Access table.
The Quantity column is of type number and the code Im using to format it is

```
Dim rstBody As DAO.Recordset
Dim orderBodyQuery As String
orderBodyQuery = "SELECT distinct CONVERT(Decimal(9,2), Quantity) FROM " + mainTable + " WHERE [" + uniqOrderColumn + "] = """ + order + """"
Set rstBody = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(orderBodyQuery, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

This results in the error:

> Undefined function 'CONVERT' in expression

As the error describes Im guessing Im using the wrong syntax here (SQL Server) but I can't find how to do this.
Please help

Comment: You should retrieve _Quantity_ as is, then format the values when displayed by setting the format (property) of the textbox.

Comment: @Gustav Ok, I will try that. Do you know how I should use format to get the expected result with two decimals?

Comment: Yes. For display (text) it would be: `Format([Quantity], "0.00")`. To retrieve numeric values rounded by 4/5 to two decimals, it would be: `CCur(Format([Quantity], "0.00"))`. To set the Format property, use: "0.00", or just "Standard".

Comment: @Gustav Thanks. If you provide that as an answer I will accept that solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For display (text) it would be:

```
Format([Quantity], "0.00")
```

To retrieve numeric values rounded by 4/5 to two decimals, it would be:

```
CCur(Format([Quantity], "0.00"))
```

To set the *Format* property, use:

```
"0.00", or just "Standard".
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprise! Access doesn't use T-SQL.

I think you want the FORMAT() function.

[What are differences between access sql](http://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.com/2013/05/what-are-differences-between-access-sql.html)

[techonthenet.com/access/functions/](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/)

Comment: The docs of CurrentDb.OpenRecordset says "The source can be a table name, a query name, or an SQL statement that returns records"..If i remove the convert and only select the quantity it works..So it is possible to send SQL

Comment: JET/ACE (the Access db engine) has it's own dialect of SQL, which doesn't include CONVERT.  (T-SQL is the SQL Server implementation of the SQL language: every database engine has a slightly different dialect)